# What's the best library for reading Outlook .msg files in Java?

Tags: java, outlook, msg

I would like to read the text and binary attachments in a saved Outlook message (.msg file) from a Java application, without resorting to native code (JNI, Java Native Interface).

[Apache POI-HSMF](http://poi.apache.org/hsmf/index.html) seems to be in the right direction, but it's in very early stages of development...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could use Apache POIFS, which
  seems to be a little more mature,
  but that would appear to duplicate the efforts of POI-HSMF.
- You could use POI-HSMF and contribute changes to get the
  features you need working.  That's
  often how FOSS projects like that expand.
- You
  could use com4j, j-Interop, or some
  other COM-level interop feature and
  interact directly with the COM
  interfaces that provide access to
  the structured document.  That would
  be much easier than trying to hit it
  directly through JNI.

Answer (score 7):

[msgparser](http://auxilii.com/msgparser/) is a small open source Java library that parses Outlook .msg files and provides their content using Java objects. msgparser uses the [Apache POI - POIFS](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/) library to parse the message files which use the OLE 2 Compound Document format.

Comment: [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) uses a fork of msgparser ([Outlook Message Parser](https://github.com/bbottema/outlook-message-parser)) and has API for directly reading Outlook messages to MimeMessage, Email or EML.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use Jython with the Python win32 extensions (http://www.jython.org/Project/ + http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/)? 
If this is for a "personal" or "internal" project Jython with Python may be a very good choice. If you are building a "shrink wrapped" software package this may not be the best option.

Comment: I really like Python / Jython, but I'm afraid in this case I won't be able to use it (exactly because it's not a personal / internal / toy project).

Answer (score -1):

Apache POI-HSMF.

You can start from the example given in below link.
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hsmf/examples/Msg2txt.java?revision=821500&view=markup&pathrev=821500

Further read library docs.