# How to create .msg file in java using javax mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

I just wanted to know, is it possible to create .msg file(that can be opened using ms-outlook) using javax mail API.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139

Answer (score 1):

I believe a .msg file is in a Microsoft proprietary format; there's no easy way to create such a file with JavaMail.

However, Outlook might be able to read a .eml file, which is in MIME standard format.  JavaMail can create such a file using the Message.writeTo method.

Comment: Hi, can we create an .eml file that cen be opened using outlook.If yes then how, I tried but its not getting opened in Outlook.

Comment: I never use Outlook so I can't say for sure.  How did you try to create the file and how did you try to open it in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, can we create an .eml file that cen be opened using outlook.If yes then how...

You can open files from the command line in Outlook.  Search for [`Command-line switches for Outlook`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6)  There is a [undocumented `/eml` switch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956693/files-that-have-the-eml-file-name-extension-do-not-open-in-outlook-200) that can be used to open the MIME standard format.  For example, `outlook /eml filename.eml`

There is a documented `/f` switch which will open `msg` files.  For example `outlook /f filename.msg`

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on *javamail*.
The module **javamail-file-transport** is a JavaMail transport that creates msg files on local disk instead of sending real email.

GitHub: https://github.com/m-szalik/javamail

Comment: It uses the .msg extension, but [they're actually](https://github.com/m-szalik/javamail/blob/master/javamail-file-transport/src/main/java/org/jsoftware/javamail/FileMsgTransport.java) EML files. `MimeMessage.writeTo` generates [EML](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0613.html) data.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives:

- Free: [jotlmsg](https://github.com/ctabin/jotlmsg)
- Commercial: [Aspose.Email](https://products.aspose.com/email)