# How to get the contact information from a msg file using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

i export some msg files from the outlook contact. (NOT email msg file)
Then i want read the contact information from those msg files using apache poi. In the website of POI, i had found an example about MAPIMessage, that read the information of a email from msg.

my question is, how to get the contact information from msg file ? Please get me some code-example.

thanks

Zhang

Comment: Do you mean the from and to email addresses? Or something else?

Comment: No. In Outlook you can save the contact as a msg file. (drop and drag some contacts from outlook to desktop, then get some msg files in desktop). I just want to parse the Information in those files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139