# Processing a .msg file in java

Tags: java, email, outlook

I am planning on parsing an outlook .msg file in Java - the message body will be a number of tables which I need to process - as such I was wondering if anyone might be able to suggest:

1. the best library for processing these messages
2. any tips on extracting the tables from the message content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` method.