# Display mail from a MSG file

Tags: java, msg

In my application (Java EE), I retrieve a MSG file and I'd like to display it in the browser the same way it could be looked on Outlook. Is there already a Java API which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

There are APIs that will (apparently) allow you to parse Outlook "msg" files:

- [What's the best library for reading Outlook .msg files in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936/whats-the-best-library-for-reading-outlook-msg-files-in-java)

However, turning that into something that will display as a web page is something else.  It is not the sort of thing you would implement an API to do.  (You might contemplate a reusable JSP to do it ... or something ... but it seems a long shot.  And I couldn't spot anything ...)

---

Maybe you should consider an alternative like OWA where the user's browser talks to the Exchange server directly.

Comment: I suspected that I would have this kind of answer but it was worth a try.